# Faster Sliding after a few hours of setTimeout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, settimeout

I am using the following code to slide a set of DIV's after 90 seconds. Initially the sliding works just fine, but post a few hours the sliding stats happening more randomly.

```
 function loadTemplateDisplayInterval()
 {
    var timeload=90000;//slide will change after 1.5 mints  
    var count = <s:property value="#request.templates.size()" />;
    var timeOut=setTimeout(function() {
    var prev=display_div;
    display_div++;

    if($("#container_" + prev).is(":visible"))
    {   

        $("#container_" + prev).hide(100).removeClass("fadeInLeftBig").addClass("fadeOutRightBig");
        $("#container_"+display_div).show(100).removeClass("fadeOutRightBig").addClass("fadeInLeftBig");

    }

    if(display_div>count)
    {   

        display_div=1;
        prev=count;

        $("#container_" + prev).hide(100).removeClass("fadeInLeftBig").addClass("fadeOutRightBig");
        $("#container_"+display_div).show(100).removeClass("fadeOutRightBig").addClass("fadeInLeftBig");

        setTimeout(function() {
            loadTemplateDisplayInterval();
        },timeload);

     }
     else
     {
        loadTemplateDisplayInterval();
     }

    clearTimeout(timeOut);
}, timeload);
}
```

The Div's are structures as,

```
    <div class="container-fluid animated" id="container_1"
            style="opacity: 0.01">
            <div class="row">
                row 1
            </div>
   </div>
   <div class="container-fluid animated" id="container_2"
            style="opacity: 0.01">
            <div class="row">
                row 1
            </div>
   </div>
   <div class="container-fluid animated" id="container_3"
            style="opacity: 0.01">
            <div class="row">
                row 1
            </div>
   </div>
```

I am unable to think, y this could be happing. The only part we noticed was when we didnt have a d3.js component, this problem didnt occur.

**EDIT: Update with d3.js code**

```
    var font_size = new Array();
    var all_topics = new Array();

    $('#' + divid).css('height', graph_h + "px").css("width", row_6 + "px");

    $.post('<s:url value="/advance/topicsWarroomElement" />', {
        setting_id : setting_id
    }, function(data) {

    var vals = eval('(' + data + ')');
            if (vals.length > 15) {

                //var temp = vals.length - 12;
                vals = vals.slice(0,12);
            }

            for ( var i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
                var x = vals[i];
                var temp_font = getFont(x.weight, i);
                all_topics.push({
                    "Text" : x.text,
                    "Size" : temp_font,
                });

                font_size.push(temp_font);
            }
```

//          console.log(all_topics);
            var fill = d3.scale.category20();

```
        d3.layout.cloud().size([ row_6, graph_h ]).words(
                all_topics.map(function(d) {
                    return {
                        text : d.Text,
                        size : d.Size
                    };
                    console.log(d.Text);
                }))

        .padding(function(d) {
            if (d.size <= 25 && vals.length <= 5) {

                return 10;
            } else {

                return 5;
            }
        }).rotate(function() {
            return 0;
        }).fontSize(function(d) {
            return d.size;
        }).on("end", draw).start();

        function draw(words) {
        console.log(words);
            var element = document.getElementById(divid);
            d3.select(element).append("svg").attr("width", row_6).attr(
                    "height", graph_h).append("g").attr(
                    "transform",
                    function(d) {
                        return "translate(" + [ row_6 / 2, graph_h / 2 ]
                                + ")";
                    }).selectAll("text").data(words).enter().append("text")
                    .style("font-size", function(d, i) {
                        return font_size[i] + "px";

                    }).style("font-family", " Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif")
                    .style("fill", function(d, i) {
                        return fill(i);
                    }).attr("text-anchor", "middle").attr(
                            "transform",
                            function(d) {
                                return "translate(" + [ d.x, d.y ]
                                        + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
                            }).text(function(d) {
                        return d.text;
                    });
        }

        if (draw !== true) {

            progressbar(divid);
        }

        setTimeout(function() {
            getTopics(setting_id, graph_type, divid, true);

        }, 2 * interval * 60 * 1000);

    });

    font_size = [];
    all_topics = [];
```

**EDIT 2**
After the suggestions made it's evident that setTimeout or setInterval go bonkers after a while. I have added a time time interval check and my new method looks as given below. But even with that I see the time itself is not correct and the difference comes wrong at many time, any way out of this.

```
function loadTemplateDisplayInterval()
{
    console.log('call load template display ');
    var timeload=30000;//slide will change after 1.5 mints  
    var count = <s:property value="#request.templates.size()" />;
    var lastTrigger = new Date().getTime();

    var timeOut=setInterval(function() 
    {
        console.log('difference -->'+ (new Date().getTime() - lastTrigger));
        if((new Date().getTime() - lastTrigger)>=timeload)
        {
            lastTrigger= new Date().getTime();
            console.log('Entering timeout '+display_div);
            var prev=display_div;
            display_div++;

            if($("#container_" + prev).is(":visible"))
            {   
                $("#container_" + prev).hide(100).removeClass("fadeInLeftBig").addClass("fadeOutRightBig");
                $("#container_"+display_div).show(100).removeClass("fadeOutRightBig").addClass("fadeInLeftBig");
            }

            if(display_div>count)
            {   
                display_div=1;
                prev=count;

                $("#container_" + prev).hide(100).removeClass("fadeInLeftBig").addClass("fadeOutRightBig");
                $("#container_"+display_div).show(100).removeClass("fadeOutRightBig").addClass("fadeInLeftBig");
                console.log('call load template display if block');
                //loadTemplateDisplayInterval();
            }

        }
    }, 10000);
}
```

**TIME LOG FROM ABOVE CALL**
This time log display that even the date difference in two consecutive calls comes incorrect.  How can this be correct.

```
difference -->30058
Entering timeout 2
difference -->30053
Entering timeout 1
difference -->30052
Entering timeout 2
difference -->30058
Entering timeout 1
difference -->9999
difference -->9978
```

Regards,
Ayush

Comment: Does the same problem occur with a setInterval call ? If the problem is with your d3.js component, it may be interesting to see the part where you use it.

Comment: @Kaiido -Yes the problem happens even if we use setInterval. I have added the d3.js word cloud code into the question above.

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval` is sadly not precise. I once created a clock by using `setTimeout(1000)` and the result was a catastrophe - large fluctuations in triggered times, even as high as +-30%.

So running a long term iterative `setTimer`, possibility in the background (browser minimized) will probably be even more off-time as browsers tend to give minimized tabs/windows lower execution priority.

What you should do is: decrease the interval by, say, ~10 times and every time you get triggered, check the actual elapsed time from your last action. When the time is within your desired tolerance, fire your code. It is really important to measure absolute elapsed time, as summing-up triggered timeouts is *not* precise and the error gets bigger with every iteration.

**EDIT**: To get the current time in milliseconds since epoch, use `new Date().getTime()`. You can save this value every time you fire your action and check the elapsed time in the in-between intervals. Just subtract the values and when the approach your interval time, fire your action again.

**EDIT 2**: Example of measuring time between intervals: http://jsbin.com/jerizemala/1/edit?html,js,console

Comment: In my case the browser is not minimised, on the other hand its on a full screen mode and running continuously, would this be true even then? Also, any hints on how to check the elapsed time? I did try doing it and it seems the browser decided to hang.

Comment: I have made an edit to give you the command to access the current time. This way you can calculate the absolute difference of the elapsed time. You can also make a benchmark of how often the setTimeout *fails* to deliver on-time. Look at this: [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/jerizemala/1/edit?html,js,console) example.

Comment: i made the change, the logic seems to be correct. But, it looks like even Date() doesnt seem to work correctly.

Comment: `new Date().getTime()` should return the exact time from your computer's clock. I don't see an option how this could not work correctly, as it is very elementary to JavaScript. However, as I have numerously stated, the `setTimer` and `setInterval` do not guarantee precise execution time. And this is probably where your problem is.

Comment: One thing I am noticing is it seems that there are multiple threads of setTimeout anonymous function that starts, which is causing the problem.  For the first few hours only one instance seems to be running, but at a later time more than instance starts.

Comment: Also, from this log it seems there is more than one instance of the code running,  the first parameter is time of run and second is last. The first one shows it being called almost every 1 second and the second that the last run is not being remembered. 1434204011  -  1434203991  =  20
1434204013  -  1434204003  =  10
1434204014  -  1434203984  =  30

Comment: The only reason for multiple concurrent `setInterval` is that you somehow (probably not intentionally) call `loadTemplateDisplayInterval()` multiple times. Investigate where you invoke that function if it could maybe be invoked more than once (e.g. some event fired multiple times).

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I have narrowed it down to the fact that it's the d3.js component that's causing this issue, not sure why. I have removed the d3.js component and everything works as expected.